# How can I read a variable selection in Excel using Taro in Julia

Tags: excel, julia

I want to read in a selection from a Excel file using Taro (in Julia). The way I do it now is:

```
roomfile=joinpath(..."rooms.xlsx")
  output=Taro.readxl(roomfile,"A2:F10";header=false)
  classrooms=convert(Array,output)
```

But this reads only the fixed selection from cell A2 up to F10. Is it possible to read such a file until the end (last not empty row and column)? If so, how? The data is always rectangular with no empty cells.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If you save the file in ods format, you can use [OdsIO.jl](https://github.com/sylvaticus/OdsIO.jl), more specifically

```
ods_read(roomfile;sheetName="Sheet1",retType="Matrix")
```

(other possible return types are `Dict` or `DataFrame`)